# Unable to run Sikuli IDE click(image)

Tags: testing, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script, sikuli-ide

I have a VB.net Project executable. I start the executable using Sikulix IDE.

[image]
**SikulixIDE1.1.0**
  **Untiled**

```
#Click application logo to start 
doubleClick("1459230114375.png")
#Login screen Enter UserName,Password,click ok
type("1459230089151.png","admin")
type("1459230150826.png","")
click("1459229716030.png")
```

**When running the code I get this error message:**

```
[error] RobotDesktop: checkMousePosition: should be L(113,545)@S(0)[0,0 1280x768] but after move is L(706,63)@S(0)[0,0 1280x768] Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was running: Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost application. You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin.

[error] RobotDesktop: checkMousePosition: should be L(575,376)@S(0)[0,0 1280x768] but after move is L(600,353)@S(0)[0,0 1280x768] Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was running: Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost application. You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin.

[error] RobotDesktop: checkMousePosition: should be L(715,402)@S(0)[0,0 1280x768] but after move is L(595,350)@S(0)[0,0 1280x768] Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was running: Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost application. You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin.
```

Comment: Have you actually tried what the error message is suggesting? Run the app as an admin?

Comment: What I meant is to run the whole IDE as admin. If you work in windows, follow these instructions: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx  to start command line as admin and run the IDE from there. See if that makes any difference.

Comment: Again, I am not talking about the application that you are testing. I am talking about Sikuli IDE itself. You should run the Sikuli IDE as admin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107598/discussion-between-eugene-s-and-tulsi).

Comment: Why we should ever run SikuliX as admin? I think the answer shall provide steps how to fix this situation, so Sikuli could run with usual permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try and run the Sikuli IDE in as an administrator, as it is being suggested in the error message. You can do that from command line while starting the terminal as an admin. You can find details how to do that [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

in python it works like this for me:

```
import pyautogui as pg

pg.click(x = 2206, y = 353)# click somewhwere on sikuli on the screen
pg.hotkey('ctrl', 'r')
```

then Sikuli can use the mouse

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your screen resolution should be 100%. "error mouse not useable (blocked) " issue should be resolved.

Comment: How do you check that resolution screen is 100%?

Answer (score 0):

Mine is windows 11, DPI set to 100%, run cmd as administrator, execute `java -jar xxx.jar` fix the issue.